# Google Maps API (Directions) throws 403 error in Payara, not in WebLogic

Tags: java, google-maps, directions, payara

I've been given the task to move our application from WebLogic 12.1.3 to Payara 4.1 and have run into an issue that I feel I'm more or less at the end of the line of troubleshooting.
We have an EJB (a Stateless bean) that has two methods, one that makes a call to the Google Maps Directions API and one that makes a call to the Google Maps Geocoding API, both using the same credentials and Googles client libraries for Java. Both methods work perfectly running on WebLogic, but after switching to Payara the one using the Directions API gives me an error. Here's the relevant part of the stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server Error: 403 Forbidden
    at com.google.maps.internal.OkHttpPendingResult.parseResponse(OkHttpPendingResult.java:258)
    at com.google.maps.internal.OkHttpPendingResult.await(OkHttpPendingResult.java:167)
    at com.google.maps.PendingResultBase.await(PendingResultBase.java:56)
    at com.somecompany.integration.GoogleDirectionsIntegration.getDirections(GoogleDirectionsIntegration.java:XXX)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

So the geocoding-method still works on both platforms, but when attempting the call to the Directions API I get a 403 back from Google indicating that my credentials are messed up, but the very same credentials work for the geocoding call. The code hasn't been changed in any way switching from one platform to the other.

What's even more confusing is that if I grab the actual URL of the call to Google from the logs and try it in my browser, i.e. paste "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?client=gme-company&mode=driving&arrival_time=1435825037&o
rigin=Somewhere&destination=Somewhere+else&alternat
ives=false&signature=nfre3XYZ2kmuDX8Qibce87ZFKQQ=" into Chrome, it works. I get a proper answer from Google. (btw, those aren't the actual credentials or origin and destination I'm using, they've been "anonymized" :-)). I've also checked that this URL (which is built by the client library) is the same running on both platforms as well as used the URL Signing Debugger on Google's developer pages, but to no avail. There should be nothing wrong with my credentials.

I'm really at the end of the line here, having spent days troubleshooting and searching online without finding a solution.

Not that it matters that much but I didn't write this code myself, and the person who did of course doesn't work here anymore :-P

Anyway, here's the code (somewhat anonymized):

```
@Stateless
public class GoogleDirectionsIntegration {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GoogleDirectionsIntegration.class.getName());

private GeoApiContext context = null;

/**
 * Initializer
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "initiating {0}", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    this.context = new GeoApiContext().setEnterpriseCredentials("gme-company", "companyGoogleCryptographicSecret");
    this.context.setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setRetryTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    OkHttpRequestHandler okHttpRequestHandler = null;
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = null;

    try {
        Field requestField = this.context.getClass().getDeclaredField("requestHandler");
        requestField.setAccessible(true);
        okHttpRequestHandler = (OkHttpRequestHandler) requestField.get(this.context);
        Field f = okHttpRequestHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("client");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        okHttpClient = (OkHttpClient) f.get(okHttpRequestHandler);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create SSL context", e);
    }

    SSLContext sslCtx = this.getSslContext();

    if (sslCtx != null && okHttpClient != null) {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
        okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    }
}

private SSLContext getSslContext() {
    TrustManager[] tm = new TrustManager[] {
            new CustomTrustManager()
    };

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, tm, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create SSL context", ex);
    }
    return sslContext;
}

public DirectionsRoute getDirections(final String origin, final String destination, final DistanceUnit distanceUnit,
        @Nullable TransportMode mode, @NotNull Instant arrivalTime) throws NotFoundException {
    TransportMode actualMode = mode == null ? TransportMode.CAR : mode;
    DirectionsRoute[] directionsRoutes;

    DirectionsApiRequest directionsApiRequest = DirectionsApi.getDirections(this.context, origin, destination);
    directionsApiRequest.arrivalTime(new Instant(arrivalTime));
    directionsApiRequest.alternatives(false);
    directionsApiRequest.mode(this.toTravelMode(actualMode));

    try {
        DirectionsResult res = directionsApiRequest.await(); // THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS!
        directionsRoutes = res.routes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new NotFoundException(e.getMessage());
    }

    if (directionsRoutes.length != 1) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Failed to fetch valid directions");
    }

    return directionsRoutes[0];
}

public void getAddress(LatLng startLocation, Location location, boolean cacheOverride) throws Exception {
    com.google.maps.model.LatLng gLatLng = new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(startLocation.getLat(), startLocation.getLng());
    GeocodingApiRequest geocodingApiRequest = GeocodingApi.reverseGeocode(this.context, gLatLng);
    GeocodingResult[] geocodingResults;
    geocodingResults = geocodingApiRequest.await();
    if (0 < geocodingResults.length) {
        //.. Code that does stuff with the result..
    } else {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Received empty results from Google reverse geocode for [{0}].", startLocation);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Google Maps Directions Web Service for your key? (in the [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/))

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, obviously, since everything works perfectly when the app runs on WebLogic.

Comment: It wasn't clear it was the same domain/webserver (is it?).

Comment: @geocodezip It is. All that has changed is which type of application server is running the application.

Comment: If I've understood things right here, it looks like the 403 is coming from Google, so we probably need to find what Payara is actually sending to the maps API. Can you use Chrome dev tools to inspect the HTTP request? It could be that something is getting mangled somewhere. Wrong headers or something? Bit of a guess at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it. The problem wasn't in the code but in the dependencies, or rather in a dependency to one of the dependencies - OkHttp. I simply changed the version and it works now.